# Начало изучения веб-программирования

Tags: php, html, книги, dreamweaver, css

Здравствуйте!

Хочу начать изучать веб-программирование. Пожалуйста, посоветуйте книги по:

1. HTML
2. CSS
3. Dreamweaver
4. PHP

которые по вашему мнению наиболее будут полезны при изучении. Чтобы были понятны для новичка и в то же время актуальны. =)

Заранее огромное спасибо тем, кто откликнется! =)

Comment: Что бы научиться что либо делать советую просто начать писать свою домашнюю страницу. И по ходу изучать что к чему. будет что-то интересно пиши буду рад помочь 437433827

Comment: Отвечу на любые вопросы. Милости просим 471167629

Comment: 2011 год был годом добра, любви и взаимопомощи? Все аськи с желанием помочь раздают...  
А сейчас... Только и видно заминусованные вопросы.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Answer (score 4):

Хороший сайт тебе в помощь http://htmlbook.ru. И про html, и про css.

Comment: Отличный сайт, там есть и информация по html, css, и практические задания. Рекомендую.

Answer (score 2):

Ну по CSS однозначно Э. Бадд. По HTML Матросов, Сергеев, Чаунин. По PHP Будилов. Сам не про, но книги у меня есть, все понятно.
Для изучения ООП Энди Гутман"Профессиональное программирование на PHP"

Answer (score 1):

Я начинал таким образом: прочитал книгу Влада Мержевича, обзавелся его справочниками для того, чтобы нужная инфа была под рукой. За небольшой период времени обрел необходимую базу, и начал учиться самостоятельно - лучше этого метода не придумаешь. Имея стартовые знания, найдите простой сайт, разберите его по винтикам, вникни в структуру. Без подсказок соберите сами. Потом двигайтесь по нарастающей. Практика - лучший способ понять язык, а не тупо заучить его структуру.

Answer (score 1):

Я когда-то начинал учить веб-программирование и была у меня книга "HTML, JAVASCRIPT, PHP и MYSQL. Джентельменский набор web-матера", автор Н.Прохоренок. Очень помогла. Хорошо изложен материал, с нее начинать учить хорошо.

Скачать можно например [здесь](http://forcoder.ru/html-css/html-javascript-php-i-mysql-dzhentlmenskij-nabor-web-mastera-1120).

Answer (score 0):

Книги нужны по мере необходимости, какие - сами потом подберете. Поставьте себе задачу:
сделать сайт со своим дизайном, в нем должно присутствовать комментирование ваших статей другими пользователям.

Итак: дизайн и верстка (тут вы выстрадаете и изучите HTML и CSS). Потом прикрутите свой шаблон с помощью Smarty (это такой шаблонизатор). Ну, и далее к шаблону с помощью PHP прикрутите форму регистрации, админку (для добавления своих статей из текстового файла) и собственно функцию комментирования ваших статей. И весь контент сайта храните в MySQL, тем самым начнете изучать создание и запросы в БД.

С помощью чего все это делать? Я бы рекомендовал текстовый редактор, без дримвиверов и другого. Для новичка главное - набить руку в коде, запомнить, что писать и зачем, код все равно будет короткий и маленький.

Answer (score 0):

По js: Дэвид Флэнаган - JavaScript. Подробное руководство.

По php: Котеров,Костарев - PHP 5.2ed.2009 ; PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования; http://php.su,   http://php.net

По html: http://htmlbook.ru

Answer (score 0):

я пользуюсь двумя книгами если, это- веб-мастеринг(Пётр Ташков), и (X)HTML-скрипты и стили (В. Дунаев)

В веб-мастеринг есть всё для начинающего и html, css, javascript +Apache

в (X)HTML - я смотрю как создавать сайты на основе блоков div

Answer (score 0):

Все сводится к знанию html ибо по сути все прочие языки его генерируют и управляют его элементами. То есть для начала изучи HTML и CSS - т. е. вёрстку. А дальше когда научишся сам верстать будешь уже генерировать его с помощью серверных языков (PHP, ASP и т.п.)
Позже пойдет высший пилотаж DOM, JavaScript,JQuery и т.д.

Правильно говорят: сначала поставь себе маленькую задачу (типа странички о себе: текст разный, ссылки на сайты и другие страницы, картинки). По своему опыту книги нужны разные. В одних проще написано, в других бывает то чего нет в остальных. Все собирай и смотри.

Dreamweaver - скорее для удобства верстки, но не для изучения. На него можно обратить внимание когда освоишь HTML.