# Книги и учебные материалы по HTML и CSS, а также инструменты вёрстки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, книги, веб-дизайн

Хочу начать изучение HTML и CSS. В интернете находил много сайтов и книг, глаза разбегаются и не знаю что выбрать. Поэтому, прошу посоветовать, с какой книги или сайта лучше всего стоит начать изучать HTML и CSS.
Также какое ПО следует использовать при изучении HTML и CSS.

Comment: Хм.. Что-то я неудачно задубликатил... Тут же не js :(

Comment: @VladSpirin, вообще-то пока не формат... Надо к одноответному как-то привести.

Answer (score 9):

Книга Муссиано "HTML&XHTML.Подробное руководство". Читайте вдумчиво. Книга впоследствии пригодится, как справочник.

Книга Э.Мейер "CSS. Каскданые таблицы стилей. Подробное руководство". Буквально учить можно эту книгу. ))

Сайт htmlbook.ru. - есть справочники, уроки, статьи, готовые решения. Много всего интересного на этом сайте.

ПО. Список достаточно широк. Я предпочитаю писать "руками", так скажем, то есть без приложений автоматической генерации кода... Я работаю в Notepad++. Итого для начинающего считаю лушей связкой ПО - Notepad++ и Mozilla Firefox последней версии.

Answer (score 9):

### Ссылки

1. [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/)
2. [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS)
3. [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp)
4. [metanit.com](https://metanit.com/web/html5/)
5. [html5book.ru](https://html5book.ru/)

---

### Литература

1. Дэвид Макфарланд, Новая большая книга CSS
2. Джон Дакетт, HTML и CSS. Разработка и дизайн веб-сайтов
3. Фрэйн Бен, HTML5 и CSS3.Разработка сайтов для любых браузеров и устройств
4. Эрик Мейер, CSS-каскадные таблицы стилей. Подробное руководство

---

### Видеокурсы

1. [Изучение CSS/CSS3 от нуля до гуру! (Гоша Дударь)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fw679JPOo0w&list=PL0lO_mIqDDFXoN83I4uVez8rIB25O4rk0)
2. [Основы CSS/CSS3 (Sorax)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsZDtOYUWvk&list=PL026CCEB5125879C2)
3. [Основы CSS (loftblog)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkmZl1Yy94Q&list=PLY4rE9dstrJzdkXYQXpZA0voVgB_0RJ_q)

---

### Интерактивные курсы

1. [htmlacademy.ru](https://htmlacademy.ru/courses/42)
2. [coursera.org](https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=css&refinementList%5Blanguage%5D%5B0%5D=Russian&page=1&indices%5Btest_suggestions%5D%5Bconfigure%5D%5BhitsPerPage%5D=7&indices%5Btest_suggestions%5D%5BrefinementList%5D%5Bpage%5D=1&indices%5Btest_suggestions%5D%5Bpage%5D=1&indices%5Btest_degrees_keyword_only%5D%5Bconfigure%5D%5BhitsPerPage%5D=3&indices%5Btest_degrees_keyword_only%5D%5BrefinementList%5D%5Bpage%5D=1&indices%5Btest_degrees_keyword_only%5D%5Bpage%5D=1&indices%5Btest_products%5D%5BrefinementList%5D%5Bpage%5D=1&indices%5Btest_products%5D%5Bpage%5D=1)
3. [FLEXBOX FROGGY](https://flexboxfroggy.com/#ru)
4. [GRID GARDEN](https://cssgridgarden.com/#ru)

---

### Редакторы кода

1. Sublime Text
2. Brackets
3. Notepad++
4. Visual Studio Code
5. Atom

### Онлайн песочницы

1. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)
2. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/)
3. [CssDesk](http://www.cssdesk.com/)
4. [Cloud9](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/cloud9/)

---

### Валидатор

1. [validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/)

---

### Задавайте вопросы тут

1. [ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)
2. [toster.ru](https://toster.ru/tags/firsttime)

---

### Дополнительный материал

1. [Путь верстальщика: с нуля до сеньора (habr.com)](https://habr.com/post/346010/)

Тут на мой взгляд есть хорошая схема и структурированное описание базовых вещей, необходимых на том или ином уровне.

Comment: PhpStorm тут с какого перепуга?

Comment: @VladSpirin, так он вроде как для php. Кстати, разве VS Code - не IDE?

Comment: Исходя из личного опыта начинающему верстальщику устанавливать IDE это ад, там функционала тонна и большая часть из того на начальном этапе не нужно, любого легкого редактора достаточно. Я перепробовал все основные извесные редакторы, мой выбор оcтановился на Visual Studio Code под Linux, хотя Atom тоже хорош, но это дело вкуса. Но если программированием заниматся, а-ля С \ С++ или Python, то лучше конечно IDE

Comment: Мое мнение по поводу вашего вопроса про IDE, они тут не нужны, не на начальном этапе, да и для верстки они вообще не нужны. Другое дело что-то массивное где несколько языков, но это не тот случай. Я тоже решил присоединится и написал пару строк начинающим верстальщикам )

Answer (score 6):

**Немного вводной информации** *(из личного и опыта моих коллег, друзей):*

Начинающему верстальщику, да и не только начинающему, всегда сложно определится, что читать и с какой именно книги начать лучше всего, так как нас окружает океан всевозможных рекомендаций. YouTube переполнен различными видео-материалами, тысячи блогов с красивыми заголовками и картинками, так и взывают к себе: *"Иди сюда, мы тебя всему научим..."* ну и так далее...

Очень важно, особенно тем, кто лишь начинает свой путь *(среди всего этого информационного шума)*, понять и осознать в каком направлении двигаться, с чего начинать и как далее постепенно наращивать свои мускулы в данной сфере деятельности. Как правильно все делать? Какие инструменты использовать? Вопросов много и двигаясь шаг за шагом, решая их постепенно, можно многого достичь.

Добавлю свою *подборку максимально продуктивных и актуальных книг, учебных ресурсов по HTML, CSS,  и дополнительных технологий связанных как-либо с версткой, и в целом веб-дизайном*, которая помогла мне начать делать что-то интересное, стремиться развиваться далее в этом направлении, а также найти первую работу в ИТ :)

**Литература (HTML):**

- “Изучаем HTML5. Библиотека специалиста”. Б. Лоусон, Р. Шарп, Питер, 2012, 303 стр.
- "HTML5: Рецепты программирования". К. Шмитт, К. Симпсон, 2012
- "HTML5. Карманный справочник". 5-ое издание, Д.Роббинс, 2015
- "HTML5: Разработка приложений для мобильных устройств". Э.Вейл, 2015

**Литература (CSS):**

- "Секреты CSS. Идеальные решения ежедневных задач". Лия Веру, Питер, 2016
- "Новая большая книга CSS". Д.Макфарланд, Питер, 2016
- "HTML5 и CSS3 для чайников ". К.Минник, Эд Титтел, Диалектика, 2016, 400 стр.

---

**Ресурсы для обучения и справочники:**

[WebReference](https://webref.ru/)
[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org)
[W3C. HTML 5](https://w3c.github.io/html/)
[W3C. Cascading Style Sheets home page](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/)
[SASS. Documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html)
[Bootstrap. Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/)
[Книги и учебные материалы по SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/784137/262779)

---

**Литература по веб-дизайну и связанным технологиям:**
*тут помимо вышеуказанных, дано больше технологий и данная литература немного выходит за рамки этого вопроса, но книги полезны тем, что они формируют общее понимание формирования веб-страниц*

- "Большая книга веб-дизайна". Т. Фельке-Моррис, ЭКСМО, 2017
- "Bootstrap в примерах", С. Морето, ДМК Пресс, 2017, 314 стр.

Хочу также добавить, как говорят практически все, кто каким-либо образом связан с ИТ:
 **учите английский язык**, так как технологии развиваются очень быстро и книги на русский язык переводят существенно позже, некоторые технологии перестают быть актуальными к моменту перевода. Старайтесь пользоваться ресурсами-первоисточниками, или же ресурсами максимально приближенными к ним (примеры привел выше).

Answer (score 5):

Согласен с iwowa. Отличный сайт для изучения: http://htmlbook.ru/. Насчет ПО: лучше на мой взгяд notepad++.

Answer (score 4):

Можно изучать на википедии, на [htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru), [постройка](http://www.postroika.ru/html/), [html.net](http://ru.html.net/tutorials/html/), для меня этот был лучшим - [s3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp).

ПО: пользуюсь Adobe Dreamweaver cs5.

Answer (score 4):

Я, конечно, опоздал на 7 лет, но учил эти языки я благодаря [htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru/) и [Head First HTML with CSS & XHTML](https://yandex.ru/search/?lr=10393&text=Head%20First%20HTML%20with%20CSS%20%26%20XHTML). И да: не советую учить эти языки по отдельности.

Лично я, очень хорошо воспринимаю все визуально и на слух. Мне было влом читать техническую литературу, поэтому я изучал эти языки по мере возникновения проблемы. Как именно? Начал с того, что смотрел обучающие уроки (Вводные уроки) в YouTube на русском. Повторяешь все действия в уроках и вуаля - ты написал свою первую "веб-страницу".

После того, как ты почуствуешь, что немного начал понимать в этих языках - начинай писать страницы без помощи уроков, создавая челендж себе самому. Если есть проблема - гугли. Форумы и YouTube-видео всегда помогут тебе. Как сказал один мне юзер StackOverflow: *"почти все ответы на твои проблемы ты найдешь в интернете".*

Кстати, еще один неплохой сайт-справочник - [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) (на английском).

Рекомендую после неплохой базы в CSS переходить на препроцессоры. Лично я использую SCSS. Очень хорошая книга для изучения - **Dan Cederholm - Sass for Web Designers.**

Comment: Не опоздали, +1 добавил, спс за личный опыт, новым пользователям будет полезно

Answer (score 3):

Насчет программ - Notepad++, конечно, всему голова, но также можете попробовать MS Expression Web. Плюсов несколько - как подсказка по коду и автозавершение, так и просмотр сразу того, что намутил.

Answer (score 2):

Лучший учебник на сайте postroika.ru. Я по нему научился и все замечательно! Очень советую! Зайдите на сайт и в меню выберите "HTML". Его можно скачать. Короче крутой учебник!

Answer (score 2):

Довольно неплохо описано: [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/html/) и [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/css/).

По софту на данном этапе подойдет *Notepad++* или *SublimeText* или *Atom* (по вкусу). Так же можно сразу с *WebStorm*, он более комплексный.

Answer (score -2):

Никакие книги по HTML и CSS читать не надо. Я как-то одну прочитал и понял, что только зря потратил время, ничего там путного нету только одна "вода". Все можно найти в интернете в виде статей (часто на форумах в ответах) в более краткой форме, главное знать что вас интересует.

Смотрите простые готовые шаблоны, чтобы понять как все устроено. Очень хорошим справочником будет, как уже выше было указано htmlbook.ru , удобный список тегов и хорошее описание.

Для верстки под Windows хорошо использовать notepad++, легкий в обращение и главное есть подсветка кода.