# Учебники по CSS

Tags: css, книги

Посоветуйте учебники по CSS для углубленного изучения (на базовом уровне знаю, хотелось бы более подробнее изучить). В поисковике искал, но больше попадались статьи и мелкие рекомендации, а мне нужен именно учебник.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Answer (score 1):

- Eric Meyer - Cascading Style Sheets. The Definitive Guide(есть на русском - CSS - Каскадные таблицы стилей. Подробное руководство. 3-е издание)
- Дронов В - HTML5, CSS3 и Web 2.0. Разработка современных Web-сайтов.

Answer (score 1):

Из предыдущего ответа, первая книга на самом деле очень хорошая. Отличные примеры, всё очень подробно и доходчиво описано. Также, могу посоветовать книгу Бена Хеника `"HTML и CSS. Путь к совершенству"`.