# Учебник по CSS

Tags: css, книги

Подскажите, пожалуйста, учебник по CSS для новичков.

Comment: Да ладно человека обижать. Учебников много, и дело в том, что все они разного качества. Наверное, не надо начинать с плохого учебника. Вот человек и просит подсказать ему ХОРОШИЙ учебник.

Comment: mikillskegg - Вы не в теме :)

Comment: Да уж куда нам

Comment: Учебник тут не при чем :)

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вот](http://htmlbook.ru) вполне читабельный ресурс

Answer (score 1):

Мне однажды была полезной тема на одном форуме [FAQ по дизайну в CSS](http://forum.mybb.ru/viewtopic.php?id=61)

сам css довольной простой и в основном его суть заключается в том что html вы создаете

```
<div id="mydiv">MyDiv</div>
```

а в css его позиционируете и разукрашиваете.

```
#mydiv
{
  style properties
}
```

А вот бог html и css это javascript)

Comment: А вот бог html и css это javascript) - это да :)

Answer (score 0):

Лучший учебник по CSS - "CSS - каскадные таблицы стилей" Эрика Мейера. [В books.ru можно купить электронную версию за 250 руб.](http://www.books.ru/books/csskaskadnye-tablitsy-stiley-podrobnoe-rukovodstvo-3-e-izdanie-fayl-pdf-614054/)