# Упражнения по HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css

Доброго дня!

Требуется срочно подтянуть свои знания по HTML+CSS.
Никто не встречал ресурс, где можно решать определенные задачи по HTML+CSS и отправлять их на автоматическую проверку? Требуется что-то типа этого: http://www.sql-ex.ru/ или http://beyondrelational.com/puzzles/default.aspx.

Спасибо!

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что уже есть в списке литературы основной вопрос про книги и учебные ресурсы по HTML/CSS

Answer (score 5):

Привет. Автоматическую проверку не встречал, но что бы перед недавними олимпиадами вспомнить всё использовал всем известный http://htmlbook.ru/ .Сначала читал [некоторую теорию](http://htmlbook.ru/faq), потом [практиковался](http://htmlbook.ru/practical), после - [протестировался](http://htmlbook.ru/test/), вспомнил всё за 1 день, неплохо выступил!

Answer (score 4):

Есть хороший учебник по HTML. Если нужны основные знания по языку, это то, что нужно. Там используются интеллект-карты. А это вообще штука прикольная.

[Вот учебник](http://visualbook.ru/b1d.aspx).
А [это](http://www.cfin.ru/management/controlling/mind_map.shtml) почитай про **интеллект-карты**

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй протестируй [валидатором](http://validator.w3.org/) просто введи адрес или загрузи файл и нажми проверить после проверки вылетят все ошибки и их описания если все в норме можешь даже поставить на сайт значек из предложенных, что мол проверку прошел. Насколько я знаю это самый популярный валидатор. Правда сам давно не пользовался, раньше он ругался на html5 Тэги.

Answer (score 0):

### **Для обучения**

[HTML Academy](https://htmlacademy.ru/) представляет собой интерактивный курс по HTML и CSS, всё 
 обучение разбито на уроке с теорией и практикой. После ознакомления с теорией 
 сразу приступаешь к практике, видишь результат своей работы, выполняешь 
 поставленные задания.

[FLEXBOX FROGGY](https://flexboxfroggy.com/#ru) позволяет изучить CSS Flexbox в интерактиве. FLEXBOX FROGGY представляет собой игру, в которой необходимо позиционировать лягушонка Фроги и других вымышленных героев игры при помощи Flexbox.

[GRID GARDEN](https://cssgridgarden.com/#ru) позволил изучить CSS Grid в интерактиве. Аналог FLEXBOX FROGGY только для Grid. Тут нужно позиционировать элементы, чтобы вырастить морковный сад

### **Для проверки**

[validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/) используется для проверки верстки на соответствие HTML-кода страниц сайта и CSS-кода на соответствие современным стандартам.

### Для написания

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/) онлайн-инструмент, который поможет решать задачи в браузере без установки ПО на компьютер. Таких инструментов множество, в интернете их можно найти по запросам онлайн IDE, онлайн песочница.