# Canvas в HTML5 - какие книги порекомендуете для изучения?

Tags: html5, canvas, книги

Возможно кто-нибудь встречал хорошую литературу по теме canvas или же хороший сайт (желательно на русском) где подробно рассказывают об использовании этой технологии.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Answer (score 4):

могу посоветовать только справочники http://www.xiper.net/manuals/canvas/ а также более полный на MDN.
На русском книг не видел, только английские

Answer (score 3):

Мне вот эта помогла: [image: Decoding HTML5]

Comment: подскажи где можно скачать?

Comment: Rutracker.org http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3975695

Comment: Я у них скачивал, когда ещё действовала моя платная подписка.
Могу скинуть, если более нигде и денег нет. – куда?