# Книги и сайты про HTML5 canvas

Tags: html5, canvas, книги

Я уже перечитал руководства для новичков. А есть ли что-нибудь для середнячков и профи на русском языке?

Comment: Это всё, что я нашёл: http://www.xiper.net/manuals/canvas

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по HTML и CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/18814/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-html-%d0%b8-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для середнячков и профи - только английский.

Видеоуроки:

- [[pluralsight-training.net](http://pluralsight-training.net)] HTML5 Canvas Fundamentals
- [[lynda.com](http://lynda.com)] HTML5: Graphics and Animation with Canvas

Книги:

- Rowell E. - HTML5 Canvas Cookbook
- Williams L.J. - Learning HTML5 Game Programming. A Hands-on Guide to Building Online Games Using Canvas, SVG, and WebGL
- Hawkes R. - Foundation HTML5 Canvas. For Games and Entertainment
- Fulton S., Fulton J. - HTML5 Canvas
- Flanagan D. - Canvas Pocket Reference. Scripted Graphics for HTML5