# Что лучше использовать: css или html

Tags: html, css

Вот заинтересовал вопрос: почему многие стараются сделать сайт на чистом CSS, без HTML таблиц? Есть ли смысл морочиться или сделать смесь (таблицы и стили)!? Мне кажется, так будет даже лучше, если стили не подгрузятся, страница будет читаемой... Объясните, пожалуйста, если ли принципиальная разница?

Comment: Ох уж эта семантика. С другой стороны - без таблиц - намного легче изменить дизайн, если очень хочется или просто требуется.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что уже есть в списке литературы основной вопрос про книги и учебные ресурсы по HTML/CSS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вопрос вообще от человека который ставит html и css на разные чаши весов.

Это все используется совместно.

Таблицы в разметке используются для вывода табличной информации, для другого существуют контейнеры, которые можно позиционировать по разному, в том числе только с помощью контейнеров(я про DIV) можно сделать дизайн подстраивающийся под любое разрешение экрана, чего никогда не добьешься при использовании таблиц.

Comment: чего никогда не добьешься при использовании таблиц// См выше. Извратиться всегда может, да поможет нам display! %)

Comment: Да поможет нам голова тех кто еще хоть что-то понимает в верстке, в макетах, ставит правильные акценты при подаче вопросов и не возникает желания написать слово "г**но"

Answer (score 3):

Сделать сайт на чистом css// на чистом CSS сайта сделать нель... можно. Но делают такое только полнейшие извращенцы(еще большие извращенцы, чем я). Какая-никакая HTML разметка крайне желательна.

Все стили СТАРАЮТСЯ вынести в CSS, чтобы отделить стили от структуры: это позволит добавить новую страницу в едином стиле с предыдущими с минимальными усилиями.

Таблицы стараются не использовать для взаиморасположения блоков потому что слишком тяжелая и очень негибкая структура.Очень непросто(извращенцы, привет!) заставить таблицу показать содержимое по-другому(`td{display:block; position: absolute}`, ага...), а если страница собрана из блоков DIV, то это много проще.

Comment: А ссылочкой не поделитесь? Уж очень интересно стало, как оно, без единого гвоздя, в смысле HTML?

Comment: Вот здесь страница 404 таким способом выполнена http://1000.tech/404

Answer (score 3):

1. Сейчас как никогда важна семантика, размещая табличные (по сути) данные в div, вы осложняете работу поисковикам в плане понимания, что есть табличные данные а что есть текст. В таблицах же много продумано по сути, тот же заголовочный тег для колонок th, заголовок всей таблицы (caption) и тд.
2. Хороший верстальщик всегда предусматривает, как будет отображаться контент, если не загрузились стили или картинки! Представьте мешанину ваших блоков div и точно такое же отображение в случае таблицы!
3. Старая правда о том, что табличная страница станет видно только после загрузки всего дерева, действительно стара как мир)) используйте таблицы не как основа страницы, а как вставки там где необходимо и все будет ок!
4. Если и сейчас не убедил, скачайте СВЕЖИЙ бутстрап! там есть таблицы, Карл!