# Посоветуйте учебник для изучения HTML и CSS

Tags: html, css, книги

Друг хочет научиться верстать. Была попытка ему объяснять, но этого я совсем не умею на уровне "с нуля"... Подскажите, пожалуйста, нормальный учебник, где обучают основам верстки. И по-новее, желательно, чтобы не было оформления лэйаута таблицами..

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: может если нужны именно основы, то лучше глянуть какие-то видеоуроки?
мне например понятнее именно из них. книги вообще не усваиваю. нужен именно визуальный вариант.

Comment: @drop_off Лично для меня видео уроки на эту тематику - просто ад. Не признаю.

Comment: я по css не видел ни разу, советовать что-то не могу. просто упомянул. да и причем тут вы? вы же не себе. может человеку видео пойдет на пользу, так как визуальное восприятие намного быстрее и понятнее, чем чтение макулатуры...

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот вам лучший учебник - http://htmlbook.ru/

Comment: как вариант я уже оставил. Он реально будет лучше книг всяких?

Comment: Я считаю, что не нужно останавливаться только на одном ресурсе. Есть много книг для начинающих довольно хорошего качества, например книги серии headfirst. В интернете много чего есть. Забейте в поисковике желаемую фразу и будет Вам счастье!

Comment: Он не лучший!Очень мало статей по верстке отдельных элементов,практики.

Answer (score 3):

Книги O'reilly:

- HTML5. Рецепты программирования
- HTML и CSS. Путь к совершенству
- Создаем динамические веб-сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL и JavaScript
- Веб-приложения на JavaScript
- Добавляем Ajax
- Руководство по MySQL

Comment: Первые две точно не для обучения с нуля и даже не для новичков (хотя тут, возможно, ошибаюсь).
А остальные 4 вообще никак не идут. Это программирование. Никак не верстка.

Answer (score 3):

Советую начать с классики [CSS. Каскадные таблицы стилей. Подробное руководство. Эрик А. Мейер](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3881079/). В своё время дала ответы на многие мучающие вопросы и расставила всё по полочкам.

Answer (score 1):

Наилучший учебник - интерактивный учебник. 
Рекомендую [HTMLAcademy](http://htmlacademy.ru). Сам проходил там курсы и узнал много тонкостей, хитрых и, главное, правильных приемов в работе верстальщика.

Answer (score 0):

C++: учебный курс
Автор: Франка П.
[link text](http://computersbooks.net/index.php?id1=4&category=language-programmer&author=franka-p)

Answer (score -2):

1. Нужно хотеть сделать сайт самому (лично я фанател на одну музыкальную группу и хотел сделать сайт с инфой об этой группе).
2. Вам нужно купить **самый тоненький** учебник по HTML.
3. Нужно начать делать сайт.

Cначала всё верстать таблицами и без CSS; → потом из этой тоненькой книжечки узнаёте про CSS и начинаете его применять, → потом узнаёте про блочную верстку (многоколоночные техники; резиновый дизайн) и переверстаете весь свой сайт → потом узнаёте про CSS3, спрайты → адаптивную верстку, SASS (всё остальное, по моему мнению, неоптимальные решения) → BEM (перестанете использовать каскад) → эммм... → что там ещё... → PROFIT! → ну а дальше — JavaScript, jQuery.

Comment: Неплохой план)) Вот я и ищу ту самую тоненькую книжечку.
Только вот с таблицами не согласился бы. Самого учили верстать блочно. Без всяких таблиц

Comment: Только не BEM!!!11!

Comment: Таблицы — самое легкое. Когда узнает про блочную верстку, то будет неприязнь к таблицам и четкое понимание, для чего и когда их можно применять. А для самого начала, чтобы разделить сайт на несколько колонок — таблицы.

Comment: AlexWindHope, только БЕМ!

Comment: Самый тоненький — это любой самый тоненький. Идете в книжный магазин и покупаете что-нибудь из серии «Для чайников» или еще проще. Вообще любой, ибо через пару недель он вообще-привообще не понадобится.

Comment: @artuska, БЕМ это отвратительное нечитабельное месиво, лично у меня, ничего кроме омерзения не вызывает, хотя, конечно, быть может, кому-то и нравиться такой вот html:

    <div class="b-popupa b-popupa__without-padding b-popupa_theme_ffffff b-popupa_direction_down b-popupa_is-bem_yes i-bem b-dropdowna__popup b-dropdowna__menu b-popupa_js_inited">
        ...
    </div>

Советовать его новичку, ИМХО, не правильно ибо и без него люди девелопят (более того, так делает большинство).

Хотя да, многим подход очень нравятся и кое где он да применяется.

Comment: БЕМ это самый идеальный способ записи и ирехитектуры названий классов. Приставка «b-» уже в прошлом. Но, самое главное, он избавляет от каскада! Вот эти ваши «.header .right-size .content span b» — вот это дилетантская жесть!

Comment: @artuska, сколько людей - столько мнений, у каждого свой подход. Не надо разводить холивар.