# Доступные источники изучения html

Tags: html

Решила изучить html посоветуйте, пожалуйста, источники из которых лучше это сделать. Заранее спасибо))

Answer (score -1):

Отличный ресурс для изучения html и css:  [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru)

А вообще, такой вопрос уже был. Посмотрите [Посоветуйте учебник для изучения HTML и CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/215494/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-html-%D0%B8-css)

Comment: большое спасибо, я здесь 10 мин назад зарегистрировалась, за повтор sorry