# Учебники для новичка

Tags: книги, photoshop, corel-draw, дизайнер

Ясного неба!  
*Заранее прошу прощения, но не нашел где еще можно было бы задать этот вопрос в сети знаний.*

Я - человек далекий от дизайнерского искусства (или ремесла, кому как больше нравится). Но возникли вопросы, на которые мне нужно получить ответы.

**Дано:** 
 1. Некоторая среднестатистическая организация, которая занимается созданием газет, журналов.
 2. В газетах есть всякие рекламные блоки, картинки, статьи и тд. 
 3. Среднестатистические дизайнеры-верстальщики.

**Вопросы:**
 1. Какие требования могут предъявляться к дизайнеру в такой организации? Например владение фотошопом или корелом? Если да, то что именно нужно уметь делать в фотошопе и кореле?
 2. Какие учебники и on-line курсы (желательно рус.) вы можете посоветовать для того, чтобы этому научиться?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

Самое лучший способ узнать требования - посмотреть [объявления о вакансиях](http://rabota.yandex.ru/search.xml/?text=%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA&rid=). Впрочем, когда видите такое: *"Отличное знание Adobe InDesign, QuarkXPress, Adobe Illustrator, Adobe Photoshop, Corel DRAW, Macromedia Freehand..."* - смело игнорируйте объявление: здесь сложили в кучу море программ. Как правило, особых изысков на этой позиции не требуется.

По программам советую использовать программы от Adobe - там шикарно организовано взаимодействие между **Photoshop** (работа с растровыми изображениями), **Illustrator** (работа с векторными изображениями) и **InDesign** (собственно верстка). CorelDRAW делает все это тоже, но к нему у многих профессиональных верстальщиков предубеждение есть.

Добавлю еще, что и CS от Adobe, и CorelDRAW - это, мягко скажем, ширпотреб. Есть еще комбайны типа [Adobe FrameMaker](http://www.adobe.com/products/framemaker.html), но ими далеко не среднестатистические организации пользуются. Хотя вещь очень крутая.

2.

Посоветую купить несколько книг по соответствующим программам. Ерунды в сети очень много, а с книгой достаточно легко стартовать до внятного уровня. Конкретных авторов рекомендовать не буду - думаю, сориентируетесь у книжного прилавка.

Comment: Спасибо, развернуто

Answer (score 2):

1. Дизайнер-верстальщик должен уметь сканировать (работать со сканером), ретушировать изображения (фотошопить), создавать логотипы компаний и макеты рекламных объявлений (иллюстратор), верстать визитки, брошуры, листовки, книги и журналы.
2. Советую смотреть курсы Lynda.com по программам Photoshop, Illustrator и InDesign CS6, можно смотреть и повторять то, что делают авторы видео-туториалов. Еще онлайн могу предложить себя ) скайп kolubo