# HTML5 и CSS3.

Tags: html, css

Какие особые отличия у этих языков от более старых версий?
Изучал HTML 4.1 и CSS 2.x.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что уже есть в списке литературы основной вопрос про книги и учебные ресурсы по HTML/CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://htmlbook.ru/html5