# Книга по html и css для чайника

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, книги

Добрый день, посоветуйте.
И желательно по `javascript`

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Answer (score 6):

1. [книга по хтмл-цсс для чайников](http://htmlbook.ru)
2. [книга по джаваскрипт для чайников](http://learn.javascript.ru)

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую отличные книги, которые сам прочёл и поставил среди домашней коллекции букварей:
     1. СSS - "Дэвид Сойер Макфарланд - Большая книга CSS "    
    2. JavaScript - "Девид Флэнаган — Javascript 5-е изд."

Answer (score 1):

Если у тебя не плохо с понимаем английского, то посоветую для изучения web-ресурс:
http://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 1):

Самоучитель, по которому, я уверен, научились html очень многие в России http://www.postroika.ru/html/content2.html
Самоучитель слегка устарел, но для старта лучше не найти.
После этой книги можно читать любой современный справочник по HTML. Для старта по CSS достаточно прочитать общие правила использования и документацию/справочники.

Answer (score 0):

А после этого обязательно [CSS - каскадные таблицы стилей. Подробное руководство, 3-е издание](http://www.books.ru/books/csskaskadnye-tablitsy-stilei-podrobnoe-rukovodstvo-3-e-izdanie-557232/?show=1)

Answer (score -1):

Самоучитель HTML4 на htmlbook http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml