# Изучение СANVAS

Tags: книги, canvas

Привет. Может, подскажете литературу на русском по этой теме? 
Книг не встречал. Благодарен.

Comment: плохо искал.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Answer (score 3):

[JavaScript. The Definitive Guide, 6th Edition/Javascript. подробное руководство. 6-е издание](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4762703)

начиная с 672 страницы.