# Где изучать CSS3?

Tags: css

Где лучше всего изучить CSS3 чтоб потом уметь создавать дизайны с возможностью продавать их хоть за минимальную цену? 
Поверхностно знаю основы CSS3 , но не углублялся.

Comment: тебе книги, сайты, или видео-уроки?

Comment: [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/introcss), [Microsoft](https://mva.microsoft.com/search/SearchResults.aspx#!q=css3&lang=1033)

Comment: практика -> поисковый запрос -> реализация.
Хорошие источники в избранное, лучшие практики - в заметки...

Comment: только руками , ставите задачу и реализовываете , лучше не знаю Но для начала можно скачать курс Русакова Михаила я первые шаги делал именно по его урокам

Comment: Дома..........................

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779