# Вопрос front-end разработчикам

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, frontend

Изучаю верстку на протяжении месяца, смотрел видео уроки на ютуб, окончил видео-курсы webformyself по верстке, а также видео уроки sorax по CSS3, но все же не получается сверстать большинство сайтов. Искал другие видео-курсы, но там все тоже что я изучал. Не знаю как продолжать обучение, посоветуйте книги, курсы, или расскажите как вы изучали верстку. Буду очень благодарен !

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну для начала нужно понимать, что смотреть курсы на YouTube - не совсем то, что вам нужно для понимания как работает html и css. Несомненно есть много людей, которые могу помочь вам узнать что-то новое, но лучше все это сделать самому. Есть множество сайтов где это можно узнать - [css-tricks](http://www.css-tricks.com/).

Так же если у вас до этого не было опята в html и css, то учить его по видео плохо. Лучше начинать с [htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/).

Когда вы получите базовые знания, можно будет приступить к наработке опыта. Попытайтесь сверстать простую страницу, на которой не будет никаких вау-эффектов(сейчас главное опыт). Постепенно начинайте усложнять работу, вычитывать, уточнять, узнавать что-нибудь новое, что может вам пригодиться. Не бойтесь задавать вопросы людям, если что-то не понимаете(вопросы можно задавать во всяких FEDs каналах в Slaсk'е).

Ах да, вот [тут](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ChtWZJpvh8D0Hz2EUuwbe94Ig9r9J6R-fKc-0hVT3p8/edit?usp=sharing) можно посмотреть на гугло-документах хороший список сайтов/видео, которые могут повысить ваш скилл.

Comment: Большое спасибо за совет, обязательно учту )