# HTML и HTML5, CSS и CSS3

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

HTML2 и HTML5 - это один и тот же язык, HTML, просто разные версии (2 и 5), или же это принципиально разные языки разметки? Как будет правильно назвать их?

И тот же вопрос про CSS и CSS3 - это разные версии одного языка, или же это разные языки?

Comment: HTML 1 не существовал никогда

Comment: Это разные версии со своими отличиями

Comment: @Darth, спасибо за замечание, исправила

Comment: @Ksenia это как `Java 7` и `Java 8` -- разные версии.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос о HTML и CSS - это один язык. А HTML 5.1, HTML 5.2, CSS 3 - это все версии языка.