# Сайт или книга для углубленного изучения html и css

Tags: html, css

Я знаю css и html на порядочном уровне - в принципе все что то дают в учебниках на подобии w3cschools и htmlbook. Однако я все равно часто встречаю что то новое в css и html. Может кто знает ресурсы где можно изучить их на более повышенном уровне?

ПОЖАЙЛУСТА ЧИТАЙТЕ ВОПРОС ПЕРЕД ТЕМ КАК ОТВЕЧАТЬ

Comment: Не правильно задубликатили!

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Практикуйтесь, читайте Веб-документации(MDN или OverApi), попробуйте делать макеты, находите подходящий для себя и верстайте. Можете смотреть различные видео про веб на YouTube, как вариант сидеть на форумах(Тостер или StackOverflow), можно узнать многое. Книги можно найти [здесь](http://frontendbookshelf.ru/)