# Какие существуют хорошие сайты чтобы изучить HTML/CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

*Хочу подучить это всё, вот и хотелось бы узнать на каких сайтах лучше всего его изучать.*

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сайт или книга для углубленного изучения html и css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772567/%d0%a1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-html-%d0%b8-css)

Comment: @AlTheOne Я же спрашиваю только сайт

Comment: @VerNick, этот сайт тоже подойдёт для изучения=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По HTML/CSS - [htmlbook](https://htmlbook.ru) 
Если учить JavaScript, то [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru), если нужна конкретно документация с примерами - [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API).

Answer (score 1):

HTML/CSS платформа openedu.ru. Курс: веб-программирование

По окончанию можно заплатить за получение сертификата, старт через 24 дня.

Сам на 1 курсе по нему изучал. https://openedu.ru/course/ITMOUniversity/WEBDEV/