# Книги и учебные материалы по SVG

Tags: svg, книги, inkscape, illustrator

Подскажите какой-нибудь хороший материал по изучению SVG?
 Желательно на русском.
Какой редактор необходимо будет изучить и использовать?

Answer (score 19):

Книг на русском по svg очень мало, но они есть:

1. Вадим Дунаев "Основы SVG"
   Для начала изучения вполне достаточно. Чувствуется, что писал книгу сильный практик. Кратко, но ёмко всё изложено. Множество примеров, показывающих самую суть. Объем книги небольшой, но всё основное, что нужно есть. От простого к сложному. Практически сразу вместе с книгой можно начинать писать свои примеры.
   Книга в формате pdf, легко найти, через поисковики.
2. SVG Essentials J. David Eisenberg есть перевод на русский
   Вот эта книга,- настоящая библия SVG. Есть всё. Изложено очень доступно и коротко. Это основной источник для копирования контента на других ресурсах посвященных теории и практике SVG.  [Эта книга на русском онлайн.](http://xiper.net/learn/svg/svg-essentials/getting-started)
3. [Интуит лекции 1-12](https://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/1063/210/lecture/5426)  Очень солидный материал по SVG от А до Я. Много примеров.
4. Сайт [svg-art.ru](https://svg-art.ru/) - теория, практика, много примеров по анимации svg
5. Сайт [yoksel.ru](http://css.yoksel.ru/)  - Статьи уже для разработчиков SVG. Некоторые разделы очень глубоко и творчески проработаны: например маски, паттерны, viewBox, анимация.
   Автор Юлия Бухвалова (Yulya Buhvalova), сейчас преподает в html академии.

**Инструменты разработки**

К сожалению ничего, такого, специализированного нет. Да в принципе и не нужно особо.
Так как svg легко правится в текстовом редакторе, например: `Notepad++`
Рисовать сложные фигуры можно в векторных редакторах: `Inkscape`, `Adobe Illustrator`.

**Оптимизаторы кода SVG**

- [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) - автор Jake Archibald
- [SVGO-GUI](https://github.com/svg/svgo-gui) - автор GreLI

Comment: Так и знал, что  изменишь мой ответ...  Скромность не плохое качество...  Но не всегда...

Answer (score 11):

[svg-art.ru](https://svg-art.ru/)

[webmaster.alexanderklimov.ru](http://webmaster.alexanderklimov.ru/html/svg.php)

[developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG)

[youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%20svg%20%D1%81%20%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F)

Чуть не забыл, еще есть [SVG_Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat)

Но лучшим ресурсом можно назвать сей сайт...  Где можно всегда найти ответ на вопрос. Только не забудьте правильно и внятно оформить вопрос, который должен содержать код, который вы питались реализовать, пояснения в чем именно у вас возникла проблема и описание конечного результата....

Answer (score 5):

**Введение в SVG, статьи и книги для изучения SVG с самых основ.**

1. Карманное руководство по написанию SVG.  [css-live.ru](http://css-live.ru/articles/karmannoe-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-svg-vvedenie.html)
2. SVG Tutorial (на русском). [developer.mozilla.org/ru](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial) (если после перехода по ссылке попадёте на англоязычную статью, то высока вероятность что можно будет перейти на русскую версию по выбору языка в меню). Или прямо с первой статьи на руссоком – [Введение](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).
3. Учебник HTML5 графики – SVG. [msiter.ru](http://msiter.ru/tutorials/svg/intro)
4. Интуит. Введение в SVG. [intuit.ru](https://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/1063/210/lecture/5424)
5. SVG Руководство. [w3ii.com](http://www.w3ii.com/ru/svg/default.html)
6. SVG Essentials (перевод книги). [xiper.net](http://xiper.net/learn/svg/svg-essentials/getting-started)

**Рессурсы по SVG**

1. [css.yoksel.ru](http://css.yoksel.ru/pages/svg-links/) (Страница с полезными ссылками по SVG, а так же много статей по SVG и CSS)
2. [svg-art.ru](https://svg-art.ru)
3. [css-live.ru](http://css-live.ru/category/svg)
4. Наиболее адекватный рессурс по всему что поддерживают браузеры, раздел по SVG - [developer.mozilla.org/ru](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG)

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую следующие источники.

Для новичков:

["Введение в векторную графику", Поляков Е. 2022](https://lanbook.com/catalog/informatika/vvedenie-v-vektornuyu-grafiku/) (ISBN: 978-5-507-45750-2)

["Векторная графика для начинающих: теория и практика технического дизайна", Поляков Е. 2022](https://market.yandex.ru/product--vektornaia-grafika-dlia-nachinaiushchikh-teoriia-i-praktika-tekhnicheskogo-dizaina/1787295764?clid=703&sku=101876883575&cpa=1) (ISBN: 978-5-04-176741-9)

[Practical SVG, Chris Coyier 2016](https://vk.com/wall-54530371_257861)

Для продвинутых:

[IconFinder > Blog](https://www.iconfinder.com/blog)