# Как реализовать такой элемент?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, svg-animation, inkscape

Как сделать такой декоративный элемент? В нем будет изменяться контент. SVG? CSS3(Transform)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Примеры анимации лого

*#1. Анимация размера текста*
Анимация начнется после клика

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:auto;
}
.check {
fill:#FE5757;
}
.line1 {
stroke:#C6C6C6; 
stroke-width:2;
}
.triangle {
fill:#3E3C3C;
stroke:#3E3C3C;
}
text {
fill:#FE5757;
font-size:28px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:sans-serif; 
font-stretch: normal;
letter-spacing: 5px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 1312 202" style="border:1px solid;">

  <path class="check" d="M11.8 47.2 121.7 169 1086.4 46.6 1222.9 48.3 124.7 188.1-0.9 47.2Z" />
  <path class="line1" d="m628.7 76.5h81.3" />
  <path class="line1" d="M1092.1 46.8 1210.7 31.5" />
  <path class="triangle" d="m89.5 130.8 110.7 25.8-77.5 9.9z" />
  <path class="line1" d="M14.6 50.1 0.9 35.8"  />  
  
  <text id="txt" x="85" y="85"     > МОИ ТВОРЧЕСКИЕ РАБОТЫ 
  <animateTransform
    attributeName="transform"
    type="scale"
    dur="4s"
    begin="svg1.click"
    values="1;0.6;0.6;1;1"
      repeatCount="1" />
  </text>
</svg>
</div>
```

*#2. Вращение надписи*

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:auto;
}
.check {
fill:#FE5757;
}
.line1 {
stroke:#C6C6C6; 
stroke-width:2;
}
.triangle {
fill:#3E3C3C;
stroke:#3E3C3C;
}
text {
fill:#FE5757;
font-size:28px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:sans-serif; 
font-stretch: normal;
letter-spacing: 5px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 1312 202" style="border:1px solid;">

  <path class="check" d="M11.8 47.2 121.7 169 1086.4 46.6 1222.9 48.3 124.7 188.1-0.9 47.2Z" />
  <path class="line1" d="m628.7 76.5h81.3" />
  <path class="line1" d="M1092.1 46.8 1210.7 31.5" />
  <path class="triangle" d="m89.5 130.8 110.7 25.8-77.5 9.9z" />
  <path class="line1" d="M14.6 50.1 0.9 35.8"  />  
  
  <text id="txt" x="85" y="85"     > МОИ ТВОРЧЕСКИЕ РАБОТЫ 
  <animateTransform
    attributeName="transform"
    type="rotate"
    dur="4s"
    begin="svg1.click"
    values="
      0 332.55 75.25;
      10 332.55 75.25;
      -10 332.55 75.25;
      0 332.55 75.25"
      repeatCount="2" />
  </text>
</svg>
</div>
```

*3. Вращение и увеличение надписи*

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:auto;
}
.check {
fill:#FE5757;
}
.line1 {
stroke:#C6C6C6; 
stroke-width:2;
}
.triangle {
fill:#3E3C3C;
stroke:#3E3C3C;
}
text {
fill:#FE5757;
font-size:28px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:sans-serif; 
font-stretch: normal;
letter-spacing: 5px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 1312 202" style="border:1px solid;">

  <path class="check" d="M11.8 47.2 121.7 169 1086.4 46.6 1222.9 48.3 124.7 188.1-0.9 47.2Z" />
  <path class="line1" d="m628.7 76.5h81.3" />
  <path class="line1" d="M1092.1 46.8 1210.7 31.5" />
  <path class="triangle" d="m89.5 130.8 110.7 25.8-77.5 9.9z" />
  <path class="line1" d="M14.6 50.1 0.9 35.8"  />  
  
  <text id="txt" x="85" y="85"     > МОИ ТВОРЧЕСКИЕ РАБОТЫ 
  <animateTransform
    attributeName="transform"
    type="scale"
    dur="6s"
    begin="svg1.click"
    values="1;0.5;1"
      repeatCount="2"
      restart="whenNotActive"
       /> 
     
     <animateTransform
    attributeName="transform"
    type="rotate"
    dur="4s"
    begin="svg1.click"
    values="
      0 332.55 75.25;
      10 332.55 75.25;
      -10 332.55 75.25;
      0 332.55 75.25"
      repeatCount="2"
      additive="sum"
      restart="whenNotActive" />
  </text>
</svg>
</div>
```

*#4. Анимация закраски текста с помощью фильтра*
Закраска при наведении курсора

```js
var svg1 = document.getElementById("svg1"),
  paint1 = document.getElementById('an_paint'),
  clear1 = document.getElementById('an_clear');
  
 svg1.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
   paint1.beginElement();
}); 

   svg1.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
   clear1.beginElement();
});
```

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:auto;
}
.check {
fill:#FE5757;
}
.line1 {
stroke:#C6C6C6; 
stroke-width:2;
}
.triangle {
fill:#3E3C3C;
stroke:#3E3C3C;
}
text {
fill:#FE5757;
font-size:28px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:sans-serif; 
font-stretch: normal;
letter-spacing: 5px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 1312 202" style="border:1px solid;" > 
  <defs>
 <filter id="filter1" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood flood-color="silver" />
      <feOffset dx="0">
      <!-- Анимация заполнения контура лого  цветом       -->
      <animate id="an_paint" attributeName="dx" values="0;600" dur="3s" begin="indefinite"  restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"/>  
          <!-- Анимация исчезновения закраски лого      -->
       <animate id="an_clear" attributeName="dx" values="600;0" dur="3s" begin="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"/>    
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
  
 </defs>
<
  <path class="check"  d="M11.8 47.2 121.7 169 1086.4 46.6 1222.9 48.3 124.7 188.1-0.9 47.2Z"  />
  <path class="line1" d="m628.7 76.5h81.3" />
  <path class="line1" d="M1092.1 46.8 1210.7 31.5" />
  <path class="triangle" d="m89.5 130.8 110.7 25.8-77.5 9.9z" />
  <path class="line1" d="M14.6 50.1 0.9 35.8"  />  
  
  <text id="txt" x="85" y="85" filter="url(#filter1)"   > МОИ ТВОРЧЕСКИЕ РАБОТЫ 
 
  </text>
  
</svg>
</div>
```

*#5.Анимация закраски всего логотипа*

```js
var svg1 = document.getElementById("svg1"),
  paint1 = document.getElementById('an_paint'),
  clear1 = document.getElementById('an_clear');
  
 svg1.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
   paint1.beginElement();
}); 

   svg1.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
   clear1.beginElement();
});
```

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:auto;
}
.check {
fill:#FE5757;
}
.line1 {
stroke:#C6C6C6; 
stroke-width:2;
}
.triangle {
fill:#3E3C3C;
stroke:#3E3C3C;
}
text {
fill:#FE5757;
font-size:28px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:sans-serif; 
font-stretch: normal;
letter-spacing: 5px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 1312 202" style="border:1px solid;" > 
  <defs>
 <filter id="filter1" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood flood-color="silver" />
      <feOffset dx="0">
      <!-- Анимация заполнения контура лого  цветом       -->
      <animate id="an_paint" attributeName="dx" values="0;1250" dur="5s" begin="indefinite"  restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"/>  
          <!-- Анимация исчезновения закраски лого      -->
       <animate id="an_clear" attributeName="dx" values="1250;0" dur="4.5s" begin="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"/>    
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
  
 </defs>
<g filter="url(#filter1)">
  <path class="check" d="M11.8 47.2 121.7 169 1086.4 46.6 1222.9 48.3 124.7 188.1-0.9 47.2Z"  />
  <path class="line1" d="m628.7 76.5h81.3" />
  <path class="line1" d="M1092.1 46.8 1210.7 31.5" />
  <path class="triangle" d="m89.5 130.8 110.7 25.8-77.5 9.9z" />
  <path class="line1" d="M14.6 50.1 0.9 35.8"  />  
  
  <text id="txt" x="85" y="85"     > МОИ ТВОРЧЕСКИЕ РАБОТЫ 
 
  </text>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

### SVG решение

Если вы планируете использовать это лого с изменяющимся контентом, анимацию контуров, закраску букв, то наверное проще использовать SVG.

*Техника реализации по шагам:*

1. Загружаете растровую картинку в векторный редактор, например Inkscape

Размеры viewBox установлены равными размерам картинки

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1312" height="202" viewBox="0 0 1312 202" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE0pt.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

2. Инструментом `Рисовать кривые безье`(красная стрелка) наносите узловые точки по контурам изображения (синие стрелки)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Сохраняете файл
4. Добавляете стили для элементов SVG
5. Добавляете текст

`<text x="85" y="85"     > МОИ ТВОРЧЕСКИЕ РАБОТЫ </text>`

6. Если вам нужна адаптивность, то помещаете svg блок в родительский контейнер и задаете ширину в относительных единицах. `width` и `height` в шапке SVG необходимо убрать

```
.container {
width:100vw;
height:auto;
}
```

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:auto;
}
.check {
fill:#FE5757;
}
.line1 {
stroke:#C6C6C6; 
stroke-width:2;
}
.triangle {
fill:#3E3C3C;
stroke:#3E3C3C;
}
text {
fill:#FE5757;
font-size:28px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:sans-serif; 
font-stretch: nmormal;
letter-spacing: 5px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 1312 202" >

  <path class="check" d="M11.8 47.2 121.7 169 1086.4 46.6 1222.9 48.3 124.7 188.1-0.9 47.2Z" />
  <path class="line1" d="m628.7 76.5h81.3" />
  <path class="line1" d="M1092.1 46.8 1210.7 31.5" />
  <path class="triangle" d="m89.5 130.8 110.7 25.8-77.5 9.9z" />
  <path class="line1" d="M14.6 50.1 0.9 35.8"  />  
  
  <text x="85" y="85"     > МОИ ТВОРЧЕСКИЕ РАБОТЫ </text>
</svg>
</div>
```

Ниже полный код

Comment: Большое спасибо - вы уже  раз решаете мою проблему с свг) Не подскажите, что вообще стоит почитать/посмотреть ля работы на свг (желательно на русском))

Comment: @Taras да не за что. Через несколько минут добавлю примеры анимации вашего лого. А этот этот ответ было бы хорошо принять, если он вам был полезен

Comment: @Taras вот [пост-подборка материалов по svg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/784173/28748)