# Изучение технологий по созданию сайта

Tags: веб-программирование

Собираюсь создать сайт, для практического изучения технологий. Начать с низов. Сначала с HTML+CSS. Потом по порядку попробовать с фреймворками, препроцессорами sass/LESS, затем добавлять PHP, JS, библиотеки jQery, написать админку и т.д.

Суть самого вопроса: возможно потом на таком сайте практиковаться переводя на другие технологии, например PHP на Python или Ruby? И т.д. Как в процессе не запутаться? Может есть у кого информация по чек-листам или планов по порядку?

Comment: Препроцессоры, а не пост))

Comment: Спасибо, ошибся. Исправил

Comment: А какова вообще ваша цель изучения всего этого? Просто, вполне вероятно - большая часть в работе вам и не понадобится. По языкам программирования/библиотекам - просто пользуйтесь тем, чем вам интересней/комфортней пользоватся на момент выполнения той или иной задачи

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще не запутаетесь, одни технологии дополняют друг друга 
 - HTML/JS/CSS, а другие выполняют одну и ту же задачу, но немного по разному - PHP/Ruby/Python. В каждой из технологий есть "куча" готовых решений. Если внимательно посмотреть на рынок, можно увидеть сформированные стеки, например:

- Ruby/Rails/PostgreSQL/Puma
- PHP/Laravel/MySQL/Nginx,Apache
- Javascript/Express/Node.js
- и т.д.

Если же погрузится в каждый конкретный стек, то там увидим окружение из библиотек и утилит.

Вы можете создать сайт из трех страниц и формы, и переносить его из стека в стека. Для знакомства с технологиями может и полезно. Но время...

Основная проблема в том, что изучить всё нереально и невозможно, стеки подвижны и постоянно изменяются. Сделать что-то полезное для себя, и тем более для окружающих, будет крайне затруднительно. Выбирайте активный, популярный стек технологий в начале, чтобы было что почитать, кого спросить.

Вот так некоторые представляют [путь веб-разработчика в 2018 году](https://github.com/kamranahmedse/developer-roadmap)