# Какие технологии необходимо знать для реализации

Tags: css, анимация, canvas

Какие технологии необходимо изучить чтоб реализовать нечто подобное - 
[проект на дрибл](https://dribbble.com/shots/3499809-AdCamp)

Я умею верстать обычные сайты с обычными анимациями, но у меня нет даже примерного концепта реализации для чего-то подобного. 
Сначала я подумал это можно сделать с помощью canvas но как реализовать shape morphing с canvas?
Возможно есть какие-то ресурсы на англ\русском где можно прочитать или посмотреть реализацию подобных анимаций

Comment: https://github.com/veltman/flubber

Comment: Ещё советую вам почитать про signed distance fields

Comment: HTTPS://Www.Shadertoy.com

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания подобного сайта вам не потребуется `canvas`. На этом сайте используется конечно же HTML и CSS, Javascript и Jquery. Вам потребуется также знание SVG для создания того синего желейного элемента(читайте про `animate` в SVG). Никакой `canvas` здесь не требуется.