# Посоветуйте книги по созданию сайтов

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, книги

Пожалуйста посоветуйте книги и ресурсы по созданию web-сайтов. Но только которые вы сами читали, изучали (гуглить и сам умею). Так же очень буду признателен за книги именно НЕ ДЛЯ НОВИЧКОМ, а для уже продвинутых. Так же буду очень признателен за ресурс, где подробно объясняются этапы создания сайтов. То есть не просто html, js и т. д. разбирают, а именно создания сайта (эскиз на wireframe.cc, дизайн в photoshop и т. д.)! Так же буду благодарен за хорошую книгу по дизайну, но не принципиально. Книги желательно на русском, ресурсы особого значения не имеет.

P.S. Только не надо кидать онлайн справочники. Меня больше интересует сам процесс создания сайта, включая рекомендацию по хостингам. И я никогда в жизни не поверю, что вы научились делать сайты чисто по энциклопедиям как w3.org.

Comment: Вам необходимо сначала по отдельности технологии разобрать, а потом все в кучу смешивать, иначе будет беда... Для того чтоб строить сайты путей много. Можно HTML/CSS/JS, можно Python + Django, с помощью .Net можно, на PHP. Вы сначала определитесь в каком направлении двигаться

Comment: По ссылке на дубликат, помотрите литературу, отфильтрованную сообществом.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы. Я искал нечто подобное https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIwKE2p6O5g . Просто была какая-то неуверенность, что я делаю что-то не так. Нужна была отправная ступенька. Теперь всё понял.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779