# Работа с CSS блоками

Tags: css, bootstrap

Как работать с CSS блоками, как интегрировать их в код, нужна инструкция для чайников, работаю с Bootstrap 4, можно оставить ссылку, где это подробно объясняется.

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под CSS блоками? по поводу обучения bootstrap вы можете ознакомиться с документацией здесь: https://bootstrap-4.ru/, а также посмотреть видеоуроки по bootstrap studio

Comment: Также: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/1365

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Официальный сайт: https://getbootstrap.com
- Русская версия: https://bootstrap-4.ru
- Руководство по **Bootstrap 4**: https://webref.ru/layout/bootstrap4
- Оффлайн справочник: https://zealdocs.org

Comment: По вашим правкам: не нужно добавлять метки в заголовки вопросов, не нужно выделять внутристрочно кодом то что кодом не является (названия языков программирования, например).